# How can i solve Magmi - Update Disabled Error

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

When i try o upload images using magmi, i get error like,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The upload/upgrade feature has been **removed** because it enabled exploits.

Relevant code change: https://sourceforge.net/p/magmi/git/ci/875893212a9c0a89d018466d023bd2fbd339dbb0/

If you **revert** this (i.e. change `if(false)` to `if($zipok)` etc.), you will be able to use the feature again, but you have to be absolutely sure that

- nobody except you has access to the Magmi web interface (for example, add  HTTP authentication or IP restriction) - Magmi itself does not secure access out of the box
- you upload the update from a trusted source

---

That being said, you are talking about uploading images. Did you try to upload an image in the "Update Magmi" form? That's not how it works. Upload the images to `media/import` in the **Magento directory**, using SFTP, then specify the image file names in the CSV as described here:

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#Image_Import_Mode

Comment: hi could you pls help me at chat @

Comment: how can i use this

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IMbnUZw.png

Comment: If you want to import images, ignore that and read the second part of my answer

Comment: could you pls join  chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42529/import-images